# H2o error on parsing a file

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science, h2o

I am parsing a file which contains UUID type too.
I cannot parse the file and get this error.

DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: 'NewChunk has type Numeric, but the Vec is of type UUID', caused by java.lang.AssertionError: NewChunk has type Numeric, but the Vec is of type UUID

Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Please provide an example of how you're trying to do it now, and a sample of the data too if possible. There are multiple ways to import data into `h2o`. What type of source is your data coming from?

Comment: I am using the flow UI.The data comes from a csv file.I have shared the csv file here. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9A7NrDPc-aQeTN0QnlpcWFROVE

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your 160MB file locally to experiment and found your data is badly formatted.

The above error you see only because the last column in your dataset is UUID so H2O make sure to set to column type as UUID however 206000 rows after the last columns shows numeric values which cause H2O to panic while setting numeric value as UUID.

I was able to load up to 206000 rows in H2O without any problem however 207000 rows gave me error so you can experiment which rows are bad formatted. You can run the following command to get all the rows from 206000 to 207000, and when loading these 1000 rows you will see the same problem.

```
$ sed -n '206000,207000p' < consumer_complaints.csv > consumer_complaints_bad.csv
```

If you can not fix your data with bad formatting at row level, you can save all the columns as string. This way H2O will ingest all the data as string and then later you can analyze the data, clean it properly then change to type properly as enum, or int or UUID. Not a good option to try because your data is already bad formatted but this way you could load all the data into H2O.